# SQL Server error: "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column" even when I SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, insert, insert-select

I REALLY review several times, that's the reason I am asking; looking for guidance...

I have one table, as the script below. Then, I set `IDENTITY_INSERT ON`. Then I try to do an insert select, (I NEED the very same ids)

I keep getting this error:

> Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Table1' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Does anybody knows why? Any set up at DB level can overrule the `IDENTITY_INSERT ON`?

I appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Script to table:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].Table1
(
    [TableId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [RowVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [AddedDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [stuff2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [LastModifiedBy] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [Table1_PK] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TableId] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The insert statement:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].Table1 ON;

INSERT INTO [dbo].Table1 ([TableId], [Name], [AddedDate], [stuff2], [ModifiedDate], [LastModifiedBy])
    SELECT 
        [RoleID], [Name], [AddedDate], [stuff2], [ModifiedDate], [LastModifiedBy] 
    FROM 
        [dbo].Table2
```

Comment: It's not about the `IDENTITY INSERT` it's about the `PRIMARY KEY` Constraint cause your trying to insert the same ID for 1 or multiples times.

Comment: @Sami. really? I have inserted pk before.. However, I will try to drop the PK and try again.
I appreciate you comment.:D

Comment: Also **do not** cut the error msg please `Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Line 2` is not the whole error message, please edit the question and add the whole error message you have.

Comment: Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Table1' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
Thank you sir, for your help.

Comment: oh!, that is because I modified a little to don't give the real DB structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you so much @Sami, you help me to realize the right path.
It turns out, you can just use, IDENTITY_INSERT to one table at time (for obvious reasons is not a thing I do often). 
When I did for several tables at time, I saw the error, but as the name of the tables were similar, I thought it was throwing an error because I ran the Identity_insert before on the same table, but it was because it was taken by the other table. 
I didn't realized until I review the Error messages one by one. :P  :D

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12650/why-is-identity-insert-on-only-allowed-on-one-table-at-a-time

Comment: That's why you should **always** `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` to `OFF` when you finish.

Comment: That's true! :D

Comment: select 'set identity_insert ['+s.name+'].['+o.name+'] off'
from sys.objects o
inner join sys.schemas s off s.schema_id=o.schema_id
where o.[type]='U'
and exists(select 1 from sys.columns where object_id=o.object_id and is_identity=1)

Comment: Even you fix this issue you will need to drop you PK too, or the error `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'Table1_PK'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Table1'` will be throw.

Comment: just if you insert wrong data. Otherwise, if the information is consistent, it won't be required. :D

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error even though I had run the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT mytable ON` command on my table. I realized it was because I was closing lines in the query script.

If you are closing each line with `;`, the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT mytable ON` command will not hold for the following lines.

i.e.
a query like

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT mytable ON;
INSERT INTO mytable (VoucherID, name) VALUES (1, 'Cole');
```

Gives the error
`Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'mytable' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.`

But a query like this will work:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT mytable ON
INSERT INTO mytable (VoucherID, name) VALUES (1, 'Cole')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT mytable OFF;
```

It seems like the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` command only holds for a transaction, and the `;` will signify the end of a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, then i found out that i was inserting an explicit value while my PK is set to **Is Identity** = true, while my relation was 1:1..0, meaning my child table uses the PK of the Parent table. `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` will only work if the **Is Identity** = true and there is no conflict in your table.